# Future Methods in Salesforce

Tags: apex

I was reading about Future methods in Salesforce and had this query - Is there any reason why future methods should be static and void?

Comment: My be, you can refer to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/79886/future-method-static  answered by @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not sure when future methods will be executed you can't rely on sending instance variables or waiting to use their results in your context. Otherwise you're waiting for a thread not executing a future method.
So to answer your question.

They are static because they can't use instance variable
They are void because you shouldn't expect a result that you use. If you want to make kind of thread, let the future method update a record and run a job to wait for results.

More on this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)